# How to run tests in production using VSTS

Tags: testing, teamcity, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to run a batch of tests every x minutes using a Build Definition on visualstudio.com. The reason I want to do that is to monitor the service if it is still alive and well. 
However I wasn't able to find a trigger for every x minutes. All what I was able to find is Continuous Integration trigger and Scheduled triggers. For Scheduled a time in day is passed. 
Can I do testing in production this way? Do I need to use a different service/tool? 
Do you know if TeamCity has such a trigger in their build definitions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scheduled trigger directly in VSTS by adding multiple times:

[image]

If you don't want to add time manually on UI, you could use [API to update the schedules](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions#update-a-build-definition):

```
PUT https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version={version}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Azure Logic App to trigger a build periodically...

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Using TeamCity, you can use a "Schedule Trigger" to run a build every x seconds, minutes, hours, or, whatever.

[Here is the full documentation on schedule trigger](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+Schedule+Triggers#ConfiguringScheduleTriggers-TriggeringConditions)

> The settings in this section define time and other conditions for automatic build triggering. You can schedule a recurring build or set a specific date and time for it.